Alien possession movie after halloween party(?)
I'm looking for a movie which I think has an alien that possesses someone on the VHS cassette cover.

The film is a horror film
In color
Released in the 80s - possibly late 70s
English language
The run time is at most an hour

I remember two scenes, just pieces, of a group of young adults investigating this abandoned building and picking up a bone then dropping it when they get inside - a dog's bone.
The last scene I remember is just a few members of the group taking off into the night in their car and the alien inhabiting one of them. 
I think it was a Halloween party they had come from to investigate this building. The alien, if I remember correctly, kills most of them. The alien craft might have landed outside building in the beginning.
What movie is this?
